# How can I merge this array or remove a key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Below is an example of the array I have compiled so far. I am generating the array from a facebook graph api call and want to remove the Array wrapping each object so I just have one list under the data Array. Preferably I need a dynamic solution as their could be more than one [0] => Array, [1] => Array and so on.... in each API request.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 21744379694_10154626935079695
                            [created_time] => 2016-10-16T06:29:28+0000
                            [from] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Tony Hawk
                                    [id] => 21744379694
                                )
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 50043151918_10154176205946919
                            [created_time] => 2016-10-15T20:04:22+0000
                            [from] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => GoPro
                                    [id] => 50043151918
                                )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I would like the array to look like this ultimately. What is the best approach here?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 21744379694_10154626935079695
                    [created_time] => 2016-10-16T06:29:28+0000
                    [from] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Tony Hawk
                            [id] => 21744379694
                        )
                )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 50043151918_10154176205946919
                    [created_time] => 2016-10-15T20:04:22+0000
                    [from] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => GoPro
                            [id] => 50043151918
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a variable `$data`, you can do this:

```
foreach($data->data as &$el) {
    $el = $el[0];
}
```

Now the wrapping arrays have been removed.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/663207)

Comment: This will do it for one of the arrays but not the second, I think it needs a count or something to get the rest.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I tested this on your example array and the output seems fine: [eval.in](https://eval.in/663207). Can you edit your question and provide a sample array for which it does not work like you want it to? An algorithm where you would just remove the array-layer whenever there is just one element is "dangerous": it might concern an array that usually has more elements, but just happens to have 1 element in a certain case: if you do that you will complicate your life as you cannot be sure of the structure you get.

Comment: Ah I see the issue, my output was slightly different in my foreach loop. That is the correct answer in this case. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if ($data && $data->data){ $new = array_values($data->data); }
```